# How to prepare to ISTQB Advanced Level Test Automation Engineer exam

Tags: istqb, certification

I would like to prepare to ISTQB Advanced Level Test Automation Engineer exam. I am looking for potentially good quality and informative material. I just found offline tranings in training centres, but nothing about printed or online materials.

I found [Test Automation Enginee](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937538087) book, but it hasn't been released  yet,  and a sample test [here](https://astqb.org/certifications/test-automation-engineer-certification/).

Answer (score 1):

ISTQB AL TAE is very new certificate, all training centres are still working on creation of materials. Which is long and expensive process. I guess free materials you can start to expect to be available in 2-3 years.

If you cannot wait so long and cannot pay money for offline training, then the best way to prepare yourself for exam is by going through the syllabus. You will find it on the page you linked in your question: https://astqb.org/certifications/test-automation-engineer-certification/ look for pdf ISTQB Advanced Test Automation Engineer Certification Syllabus.

Comment: I would be able to pay for paid online/offline materials, but there isn't any.

Answer (score 1):

There is one webpage where you can ideally prepare for your ISTQB test exam, but only in **German**! I am not quite sure whether you speak german ! An english version is planned also. For those who want to pass / learn for the exam please find the link below (Germanspeaking) :

[Smartwebapps ISTQB](https://smartwebapps.de/)

Courses are available for:

- ISTQB Foundation
- ISTQB Advanced Testmanager
- ISTQB Advanced Technical Test Analyst
- ISTQB Advanced Test Analyst
- Agile Tester

In case that you don't speak German, maybe it helps other (germanspeaking) people who wants to pass /learn for the exam.

Comment: This is really great! It is also language course for me for professional german.

Answer (score 1):

Full list of trainings provided at youtube by Neeraj Kumar Singh.

I have personally attended his ISTQB Foundation training and cleared the certification with his notes and now he has upload Test Automation CTAL and all other training on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLj5VKaW115t34PmSb5e1C2_fANeqGvDDN

Comment: Thank you for sharing this playlist!